# Unable to make two loops into one to meet both requirements

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

My scraper when follows some links to get to the target page, it finds that there are two types of element to deal with. Few pages contains the first pattern while the other contains the second. I wanted to make any conditional statement or something like try/except block in my script so that it will try with the first one, if failed, it will go for the other and try that. I can't get any idea how to do this. Hope there is any suggestion I'm gonna get here.

```
for item in docs.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pv-top-card-section__information')]"):
    name = item.find_element_by_xpath(".//h1[contains(@class,'pv-top-card-section__name')]")
    print(name.text)

for item in docs.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'org-top-card-module__details')]"):
    name = item.find_element_by_xpath(".//h1[@title]")
    print(name.text)
```

Comment: So you want to combine the two loops into 1? Sorry, can you be more specific?

Comment: Would appreciate if you could edit that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Selenium, you could store your xpaths in a list and loop through them until you find your match. Something like:

```
search_paths = [
    ("//div[contains(@class,'pv-top-card-section__information')]",
     ".//h1[contains(@class,'pv-top-card-section__name')]"),
    ("//div[contains(@class,'org-top-card-module__details')]",
     ".//h1[@title]"),
    # etc.
]

# your init code

for elements_path, item_path in search_paths:
    try:
        for item in docs.find_elements_by_xpath(elements_path):
            name = item.find_element_by_xpath(item_path)
            print(name.text)
        break   # all passed, you can remove the break to try all patterns
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:  # be sure to import it
        pass  # let it continue with the next pair of paths from the search_paths
```

Also, this will capture the `NoSuchElementException` for both the elements path, and the item path within it, and in both cases it will attempt the next pattern - you can surround the inner `item.find_element_by_xpath(item_path)` with the same `try..except` block to deal with not-found exceptions on an item level instead of moving to the next elements path.

Comment: Thanks sir zwer, for your robust and effective solution. This is exactly what i was expecting to have.